# How to limit the number of digits input?

Tags: python

I am requesting someone to tell me a program that asks a user to input only 9 digits. Number `0` not at start but having 9 digits.

How can I limit the number of digits?

For example:

```
Num=int(input('please Enter a Number'))
if num?!
```

Please help me soon.

Comment: convert it into a `list` and check `len` of list. Also you might not need to convert it into int and check the `str` directly

Comment: take the input. check the input. show an appropriate message if the input doesnt fit the criteria.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent!" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got this right this should work:

```
a=input()
if len(a)==9 and a[0] != '0' and a.isdigit():
  #if you want it to be integer
  a=int(a)
  do something
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You need to check if the input is actually a digit before converting it using `if a.isdigit()`

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understood correctly you need a program that asks the user to enter exactly 9 digits. In that case it's pretty simple.

```
i = input("Enter a nine digit number: ")

if len(i) != 9:
    print("You must enter 9 digits!")
    quit()

if not i.isdigit():
    print("Your input must be a number!")
    quit()

# num is a 9 digit integer
# i is a 9 digit string
num = int(i)
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the above code. Also, what will happen if I give input as "012345678"?

Comment: Also its suppose to be `if` not `If`

Comment: I haven't wrote a python code in a long time. Care to tell me exactly where the syntax error is?

Comment: I do understand what you mean by putting 0 in the start. But that could be easily fixed by just using the in variable instead.

Comment: The syntax error is `in` cannot be a variable, it is a keyword in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
num = input('Please enter a number')

if not num[0] == "0" and len(num) == 9 and num.isdigit():
        # You can print a message or cast the num into an integer here
        # like this: input_number = int(num)
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

So what's happening here is that the program will accept the user input and evaluate if the first digit is **NOT** 0 **AND** that the length is exactly 9 characters.

Comment: No you cant cast if input is `"1        "` 1 followed by 8 spaces

Comment: Edited my code, if you want to check if the whole string is a digit then you just need to add .isdigit() into the if statement.

Comment: Numbers must be 9 digits example 615449080 but  0 can't be the first digit.

Comment: Yeah, it should be that's why there is len(num) == 9 to check if the user input is exactly nine characters/digits and not num[0] == "0" to check if the first digit is not 0.